# Why are tests running in production mode and causing my script/runners to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have some script/runners set up in a cron job, but according to the logs, I'm getting this error below.  First, I'm not sure why Test::Unit automatic runner is happening in production to begin with. I don't have autospec or autotest going on.  Secondly, I'm not sure how to resolve this pesky invalid option error.  I'm using the javan-whenever gem to handle the cron schedule.  Any help out there?

```
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors

invalid option: -e
Test::Unit automatic runner.
Usage: /apps/ion/releases/20091210210633/script/runner [options] [-- untouched arguments]

-r, --runner=RUNNER              Use the given RUNNER.
                                 (c[onsole], f[ox], g[tk], g[tk]2, t[k])
-n, --name=NAME                  Runs tests matching NAME.
                                 (patterns may be used).
-t, --testcase=TESTCASE          Runs tests in TestCases matching TESTCASE.
                                 (patterns may be used).
-I, --load-path=DIR[:DIR...]     Appends directory list to $LOAD_PATH.
-v, --verbose=[LEVEL]            Set the output level (default is verbose).
                                 (s[ilent], p[rogress], n[ormal], v[erbose])
    --                           Stop processing options so that the
                                 remaining options will be passed to the
                                 test.
-h, --help                       Display this help.

Deprecated options:
    --console                    Console runner (use --runner).
    --gtk                        GTK runner (use --runner).
    --fox                        Fox runner (use --runner).
```

Comment: Can you post the full command that `whenever` is running on the cron schedule to call `script/runner`?

Comment: Doug, this is what gets inserted in the crontab:

/apps/ion/releases/20091210210633/script/runner -e production "Item.purge_items" >> /apps/ion/current/log/cron.log 2>&1

Answer (score 5):

This is because something in your environment is requiring `Test::Unit`. I was having the same problem running `rails runner` in a Rails 3.1.0 application, and it was because we had `gem test-unit` in our Gemfile for all groups, rather than just for the test group where it was actually needed. Once I moved it into the test group, my runners ran as expected.

This code seems to be the culprit:

```
# test_unit/lib/test/unit.rb
at_exit do
  unless $! || Test::Unit.run?
    exit Test::Unit::AutoRunner.run
  end
end
```

If you can't remove the requirement on `Test::Unit`, you can add this hack somewhere in your environment to prevent `AutoRunner` from auto-running:

```
Test::Unit.run = true
```

Comment: I met the same problem when I migrate my test cases from unit test to rspec. After I added those line to my test.rb env file, the issue was resolve.

The final solution from my end is, completely remove all unit test dependencies.